# Unity TCP server/client

Tags: c#, tcp, unity-game-engine

I'm sorry but I'm kinda having a confusing problem here...

I was using Unity recently and try to make a simple TCP server that can broadcast through all its clients, also to himself where the server itself is one of the client, like chat room or something.

so I did successfully done so, but the problem is, all the data that received by the client is actually twice of the initially data send from client, below is the example of my code

```
        public void broadcast(string data)
        {
            print("Broadcast");
            byte[] dataByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            print(ClientList.Count);
            for(int x = 0; x<ClientList.Count;x++)
            {
                ClientList[x].Send(dataByte);
                print ("something" +ClientList[x].Send(dataByte));
                print ("loop");
            }
        }
```

and this is how the client will receive it

```
    private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        print ("ReceiveData Client");
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            int x = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            print("Receiving Data...");
            print (x);
            if (x > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, x));
                string content = sb.ToString();
                print("Data Received: " + content);
                //string[] data = content.Split(';');
                //for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                //{
                    this.ProcessData(x, content, handler);
                //}
                sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
                handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), handler);
            }
            else
            {
                print("Connection Closed...");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            print(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I try to send `test;this is client`
and the result is below

```
Broadcast
1
something20
ReceiveData Client
loop
Receiving data...
40
Data Received: test;this is client test; this is client"
```

I don't know what or how this went wrong, any help will be appreciated. Thanks b4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is within these two lines:

```
ClientList[x].Send(dataByte);
print ("something" +ClientList[x].Send(dataByte));
```

Notice how you've executed `ClientList[x].Send(dataByte)` twice? That's why you're getting it 2 times on the receiving end. Just remove one of the two lines and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh my God! How stupid of me. Thank you so much for pointed that out.